# How do I query for random rows AND track what has been queried (that's the important part)

Tags: php, mysql

I already know how to do a random mysql/php query, but how do I track what has already been queried a row isn't pulled again. Use case: A quiz that has 10 questions. The questions need to be in random order. How can I track that questions (rows) 2,5,6,8,9 have already been answered, but questions 1,3,4,7,10 remain. Here's what I have so far:

```
$current_test = $_SESSION['testid'];
// v v v query for this TEST
$tests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_tests WHERE the_tests.testid=$current_test");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($tests);
// ^ ^ ^ query for this TEST


// v v v query for the QUESTIONS from this Test
// Generate
if ($test['randomize']==1){
    $offset_result = mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test");//SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM the_questions WHERE `qid` NOT IN (1,5,6) AND the_questions.test_id_q=1
    $offset_row = mysql_fetch_object($offset_result);
    $offset = $offset_row->offset;
    $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
}else{
    $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test");
}
$totalQuestions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test");
$totalQs = mysql_num_rows($totalQuestions);
$testQ = mysql_fetch_array($questions);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you can always use session to store the id of the questions that has already been answered. or you can add another field in your table and you will update it when the question is answered and in your query you will limit it so that those with the answered field would not be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

Assuming $_SESSION['qList'] is an array that looks like this:

```
$_SESSION['qList'] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

When the user submits a question, there is a <input type="hidden" value="5"...> where the value is the current question ID. **$eliminateQ** below is this question ID:

```
$_SESSION['qList'] = array_diff($_SESSION['qList'],array($eliminateQ));
$_SESSION['qList'] = array_values($_SESSION['qList']);
$questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tan_questions WHERE test_id_q=$current_test AND qid IN (".implode(',',$_SESSION[qList]).") ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

This results in an updated qList array without ID number 5:

```
$_SESSION['qList'] = array(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10);
```

And the whole thing goes on until no questions are left. There is an if() statement in that instance forwarding the user on to the results page. Viola!

Thanks, @pixeline, for your insight. I took your **NOT IN** and reversed it to **IN**. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to complement that SQL WHERE clause with `NOT IN (5,23,45);`

So basically keep an array with each random item ID value and feed it to your SQL clause.

```
mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test AND the_questions.id NOT IN (".implode(',',$excluded).")");
```

Now, this raises another question: the $excluded array. Should it be a temporary exclusion  or should it be permanent?
If it should not be permanent, then store it in a session (ex: $_SESSION['excluded'] )
If the user comes 3 days later, he will probably be able to re-answer that question.

If that has to be permanent, then store the fact that that question has been answered in a column dedicated to that, or, simply check if there is an answer ?

```
mysql_query("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM the_questions WHERE the_questions.test_id_q=$current_test AND the_questions.answer ==''");
```

Comment: Thanks pixeline. I think that's what I needed. It does not have to be permanent and should be stored as a session variable. I look forward to giving this a shot.

Comment: well, I tried this and it doesn't seem to work, though I think it should. Here's the straight query (no PHP) just for yucks:

`SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS offset FROM tan_questions WHERE tan_questions.test_id_q=1 AND tan_questions.qid NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

Even though I've excluded queries from rows 1-5 they still get displayed. I'm stumped.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like this?

`SELECT * FROM tan_questions WHERE qid NOT IN (135,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10`  ?